# ContentChild undefined when calling inside nested component

Tags: angular, angular-content-projection

I have the following component structure:

in `app.component.html`:

```
<placeholder *ngFor="...">
  <visual-comp [id]="..."></visual-comp>
</placeholder>
```

in `placeholder.component.html`:

```
<renderer>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</renderer>
```

in `renderer.component.html`:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

The problem is the following, when I'm trying to access `<visual-comp ...></visual-comp>` projected inside the `rederer` component, using `@ContentChild`, I'm getting `undefined`, while in `placeholder.component.ts` I can access it.

So here's pat of my `renderer.component.ts`:

```
@Component(...)
export class RendererComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChild(VisualCompComponent) public _visualCmp!: VisualCompComponent;

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    console.log('Visual Component', this._visualCmp); // Outputs: Visual Component undefined
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm recall trying this before with different `select` attributes and `ngProjectAs` without success. I think it's this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16299)

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `ContentChildren` with a `descendants` parameter instead.

```
@ContentChildren(VisualCompComponent, {descendants: true}) _visualCmps!: QueryList<VisualCompComponent>;
```

The only difference is that in this case you receive a `QueryList` of elements, not a single element.

Otherwise, if you don't want to use `ContentChildren`, I think you will need to have a public reference to the content in the `VisualCompComponent` and then access that public reference from the parent component.

Comment: No, it still shows undefined (first and last props of QueryList)